# Tag remove request [.net-5.0]

Tags: support, tags, burninate-request

[.net-5.0](/questions/tagged/.net-5.0) is invalid. There is nothing .net 5.0. Latest .NET version is [.net-4.5](/questions/tagged/.net-4.5).

By  [.net-5.0](/questions/tagged/.net-5.0) usually either [.net-4.5](/questions/tagged/.net-4.5) or [c#-5.0](/questions/tagged/c%23-5.0) is referred.

Therefore in my opinion, the tag [.net-5.0](/questions/tagged/.net-5.0) should be removed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are currently no questions assigned to the tag.

The tag will be removed automatically by system processes the next time they run, usually once a day.

Comment: Is it true that this will be removed, cause some users have earned reputation in this tag http://stackoverflow.com/tags/.net-5.0/topusers

Comment: That's because @Tilak edited the questions that used this tag just a few hours ago.

Comment: @Uphill, thats right. I edited, and removed the tag in the only question (for the same reason mentioned in the question)